# save file in cache or temp dir android api 30 or in gallery and hide image?

Tags: android, android-studio, file

I need to save file or image file that should not appear in gallery. How to approach this?
I thought of using cache dir or `.nomedia` but how do I save there without file API and with mediastore API on android API level 30?

I'm using similar code to save image, but how do I save it on a temp dir or .nomedia dir or anywhere and hide from appearing in gallery?

```
Bitmap imageBitmap;

OutputStream outputStream ;


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
        {
            ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,"Image_"+".jpg");
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE,"image/jpeg");
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH,Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + File.separator+"TestFolder");
            Uri imageUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,contentValues);
            try {
                outputStream =  resolver.openOutputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(imageUri) );
                imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,outputStream);
                Objects.requireNonNull(outputStream);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Image Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Image Not Not  Saved: \n "+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Comment: "I need to save file or image file that should not appear in gallery" -- save it in `getFilesDir()` or `getCacheDir()` (methods on `Context`).

Comment: Thanks for replying. It will be great to see an example of `getFilesDir()`/ any dir usage in API>29. Should I use File API directly on API>29?

Comment: val pictures = cacheDir
        val rpi = File(pictures, getString(R.string.app_name))
        if (!rpi.exists()) if (rpi.mkdirs()){
        val snapshot = File(rpi, "title")
        val stream: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(snapshot)
        imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, stream)
        stream.flush()
        stream.close()}

Comment: "It will be great to see an example of getFilesDir()/ any dir usage in API>29" -- the use of `getFilesDir()` has not changed since API Level 1. "Should I use File API directly on API>29?" -- for `getFilesDir()`, yes. Pretty much any method on `Context` that returns a `File` will give you a location that your app can read from and write to using filesystem APIs like `File`.